# Creating a new rdd from another rdd in Python

Tags: python, pyspark, rdd

I am completely new to pysparks and rdd. I am trying to understand how rdd works and I am having problems accessing part of the data in a rdd. I would like to select a few columns from an existing rdd and create a new rdd.

An example below:

```
user_rdd = [Row(id=u'1', first_name=u'Steve', last_name=u'Kent', email=u's.kent@email.com'),Row(id=u'2', first_name=u'Margaret', last_name=u'Peace', email=u'marge.peace@email.com')]

display(user_rdd)

| email                 | first_name | id | last_name
| s.kent@email.com      | Steve      | 1  | Kent
| marge.peace@email.com | Margaret   | 2  | Peace
```

How to select 2 columns from user_rdd and create a new rdd like below?

```
| id | first_name | last_name | full_name
| 1  | Steve      | Kent      | Steve Kent
| 2  | Margaret   | Peace     | Margaret Peace
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's probably the simplest way to do what you are after (although your RDD looks like it was derived from a `DataFrame`)

```
from pyspark.sql import Row

user_rdd = sc.parallelize([
    Row(id=u'1', 
        first_name=u'Steve', 
        last_name=u'Kent', 
        email=u's.kent@email.com'),
    Row(id=u'2', 
        first_name=u'Margaret', 
        last_name=u'Peace', 
        email=u'marge.peace@email.com')
])

new_rdd = user_rdd.map(lambda row: Row(
        first_name=row.first_name, 
        last_name=row.last_name, 
        full_name=row.first_name + ' ' + row.last_name))

new_rdd.take(2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
user_rdd = [Row(id=u'1', first_name=u'Steve', last_name=u'Kent', email=u's.kent@email.com'),
            Row(id=u'2', first_name=u'Margaret', last_name=u'Peace', email=u'marge.peace@email.com')]
rdd = sc.parallelize(user_rdd).map(lambda x: Row(fullname=' '.join([x['first_name'], x['last_name']]), **x.asDict()))
print(rdd.collect())
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you want to do it through an RDD because a list of rows is essentially a DataFrame and it is easier to select a column and concatenate it there. It is also more efficient than using RDDs.

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql.functions import concat_ws

user_rdd = [Row(id=u'1', first_name=u'Steve', last_name=u'Kent', email=u's.kent@email.com'),Row(id=u'2', first_name=u'Margaret', last_name=u'Peace', email=u'marge.peace@email.com')]

user_df = spark_session.createDataFrame(user_rdd)

user_df.select(user_df.id, user_df.first_name, user_df.last_name,  concat_ws(' ',user_df.first_name, user_df.last_name).alias('full_name')).show()
```

This will give you the output as DataFrame:

```
+---+----------+---------+--------------+
| id|first_name|last_name|     full_name|
+---+----------+---------+--------------+
|  1|     Steve|     Kent|    Steve Kent|
|  2|  Margaret|    Peace|Margaret Peace|
+---+----------+---------+--------------+
```